# How do you debug Meteor apps on the client-side using WebStorm?

Tags: meteor, webstorm

The WebStorm debugger connects to Chrome and the console output is displayed inside WebStorm, but none of the breakpoints trigger, nor do the watches work.

I'm pretty sure it is because of the hash Meteor adds to the end of all the JavaScript files (e.g. .../workflow.js?ae719ebc9f74248a8099499f8cb3b751ac3ad098). If I specify the URL with the hash as the "Remote URL" for my JavaScript file in WebStorm, then breakpoints and watches work, but a new, read-only copy of the JavaScript file is opened in WebStorm.

Can I disable these hashes somehow, or is there some setting in WebStorm to ignore them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try WebStorm 6 EAP — http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+6+EAP It seems this issue is fixed.

Comment: Yip, WebStorm 6 EAP fixes the problem. If you specify the "Remote URL" of the file you want to debug without the hash, breakpoints trigger, watches work, etc.